# Way to change Windows (7) monitors settings via script

Tags: windows-7, vbscript, batch-file, multiple-monitors

i bought a new TV mainly as second monitor to my PC and I often need to change settings (extend display for movies, duplicate display for gaming, disable for work'n'browsing).

Is there a way to switch among those settings via some script (batch most likely or VBS, whatever) so I dont't need to crawl through GUI all the time? I am veeery lazy... Thanks

Comment: Hi veeery lazy, I'm James. If the program has different shortcuts do different things, right click on the shortcut -> Properties. Then write batch programs to mimic the shortcuts.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Firstly, not sure if you know the shortcut

```
Windows + P
```

2 buttons seems pretty easy!

but, you could write a batch file to run the programs with the appication displayswitch.exe included. displayswitch comes with windows 7 so you can have a batch file with:

```
DisplaySwitch.exe /external
notepad.exe
```

then use this batch file to open notepad and it will always open and switch to the external display only.

the following options are available:

```
Extend Display
DisplaySwitch.exe /extend

2nd monitor
DisplaySwitch.exe /external

Computers Monitor
DisplaySwitch.exe /internal

Duplicate Display
DisplaySwitch.exe /clone
```

Martyn

Comment: Uh... kinda embarrassing, but win+P was really all I needed :-D . Thanks.

Comment: lol, you said you were lazy, but too lazy for 2 buttons! i thought that was just me! :p

Comment: Well I knew that some sort of this sortcut is often on notebooks as the 'Fn'+sth key combination and I didn't cared too much abut the win key... well win+P is maybe the only handy shortcut

Comment: I still appreciate all the options listed in the batch file example. I'm dual booting a mac and my monitors reset to duplicate every time I go back to Windows. This way I can just run a script on start up to set things up how I like.

Comment: I use TeamViewer to log into a desktop with dual monitors, but wanted to get that machine into single monitor mode when I connect remotely -- this works great for that purpose.

Comment: There are a lot of great shortcuts using the windows key. Win+E for the explorer, Win+D to minimize all, Win+L to lock your computer, Win+Arrows to snap to an edge, the list goes on and on at http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Windows_7.html

Answer (score 2):

You can make a scrip with choose like i did:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO 1.Monitor 2 i TV Duplicate
ECHO 2.Monitor 2 i Monitor 3 Extended
ECHO 3.Monitor 2 i TV Extended
ECHO.

CHOICE /C 123 /M "Izbor:"

IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO Mon2TvExt
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO Mon2Mon3Ext
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Mon2TvDupl

:Mon2TvDupl
ECHO 1.Monitor 2 i TV Duplicate

Duplicate Display
DisplaySwitch.exe /clone

GOTO End

:Mon2Mon3Ext
ECHO 2.Monitor 2 i Monitor 3 Extended

DisplaySwitch.exe /external

GOTO End

:Mon2TvExt
ECHO 3.Monitor 2 i TV Extended

Extend Display
DisplaySwitch.exe /extend

GOTO End

Pause
```

The TV is number 1, and two monitors are number 2 and number 3.